# How can I remove a heading/trailing processing instruction with lxml

Tags: python, lxml, processing-instruction

How can I remove a processing instruction which is a sibling of the root element in a XML tree?

I can't find any function to do that, and the classic way doesn't work because a head/tail processing instruction has no parent:

```py
from lxml import etree

root = etree.XML("<ROOT/><?foo?>")
tail = root.getnext()
parent = tail.getparent()  # parent is None
parent.remove(tail)
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/demo_remove_tail_pi.py", line 6, in <module>
    parent.remove(tail)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'remove'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is due the Processing Instructions being generated outside of the root XML tree. This was brought up as a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/lxml/+bug/479613) many years ago on the LXML's website, but unfortunately it does not look like an appropriate fix was ever implemented.

One of the users on the thread provided a (hackyish) way to remove Processing Instructions that were generated in this manner. Simply take the tag, append it to the root element, and then remove it.

> Unlike some other XML libraries, lxml allows an element to occur in one place. That is, you can not copy an element to another place; attempting that moves it to the new location, removing it from the old.

```
from lxml.etree import XML, tounicode

root = XML("<ROOT/><?foo?>")

print(tounicode(root.getroottree()))
>>> <ROOT/><?foo?>
tail = root.getnext()
root.append(tail)
root.remove(tail)
print(tounicode(root.getroottree()))
>>> <ROOT/>
```